# calling method webService (WCF) from iOS objective C)

Tags: ios, json, web-services, wcf

I want calling method webService by parameter Json from IOS, but I received an error.

Code Server Side (WCF):

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/test/{input}")]
    int test(string input);
```

I want get input (parameter method and url) = typeof (Json)

Code Client Side (iOS-objective C) :

```
NSString *json = [self convertToJson:myObject];
NSString *urlComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://test.com/Service.svc/test/",json];

    urlComplete = [urlComplete stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlComplete]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                 if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil) {
                     NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                     NSLog(@"Data Recived:\n %@",string);
                 }
                 else{
                     NSLog(@"Error %@",[connectionError description]);
                 }
             }];
```

The webService is being tested by windowsPhone and returns OK but doesn't work with iOS.
Please help me!
thanks:)

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
    <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
    <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
    </BODY></HTML>
i'm get this Error.

Comment: So what is your URL?  It is unusual to put JSON in the GET URL. Normally you would POST it.

Comment: this method is OK with WindowsPhone and i get result in windowsPhone,but it doesn't work with iOS. :-(

Comment: You need to examine the URL that is produced and work out why your server says it is invalid.

Comment: "Bad Request - Invalid URL" - can you quote an example of the URL you're trying to open ?  I'm also surprised you're attempting to put JSON within a URL.... this isn't allowed.

Comment: what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error description "HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid." clears that url you are passing is incorrect. Please cross check with windows team if they are appending the JSON to the get URL.

Generally, if you want to post data you can set the requestdata which is JSON and go for either a PUT or POST request instead of GET request.